# Return two or more max equal values

Tags: r, dataframe

It is my intent to return the time of day of the column where the most measures were taken. As an example, I found the highest numbers in this to be 16:10 and 16:20. I am using the `which.max(col)` function but it returns only one occurrence, not all. What is the best way to return two (or more) equal maximum values?

Update: If I sum up based on column `colSums` how can I return as well the max values? (eg. 16:10 and 16:20)
Data structure:

[image]

Desired output: 16:10  16:20

**Sample data:**

```
structure(list(Duration = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), `16:00` = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `16:10` = c(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0), `16:20` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 1, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Duration = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `16:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the `max` value with the values in the dataframe and return column names which has at least 1 occurrence of the max value.

```
tmp <- df[-1]
names(tmp)[colSums(tmp == max(tmp)) > 0]
#[1] "16:10" "16:20"
```

For the update this should work -

```
tmp <- colSums(df[-1])
names(tmp)[tmp == max(tmp)]
#[1] "16:10" "16:20"
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
colnames(df)[apply(df,2,function(x) any(x == max(df[-1])))]
[1] "16:10" "16:20"
```

Answer (score 2):

This also can be done through the combination of base R and `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)

df[-1] %>%
  select(where(~ sum(.x) == max(colSums(df[-1])))) %>%
  names()

[1] "16:10" "16:20"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
v1 <- sapply(df1[-1], max)
names(which(v1 == max(v1)))
#[1] "16:10" "16:20"
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     summarise(across(-Duration, max)) %>% 
     pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
     filter(value == max(value))%>% 
     pull(name)
[1] "16:10" "16:20"
```